compounding in short positions
Why does compounding doesn't work in short positions?
Let's say I have following mini time series
5
6
4
2.5
Returns are -20%, 33% and 37.5%. So compounding return equals to 46.67% = 0.8 * 1.33 * 1.375. But the return is 50% = 1 - 2.5/5.
How one can reconcile these numbers? Why do we get two different returns?

The 'trick' with short positions is to first compound the asset's returns, and only then to apply the position weights, i.e. -1 in your case. See also this answer How to calculate holding period return of a long-short strategy?
The cumulative asset returns are 20%, -20% and -50%. Multiply by the initial weight of -1, and you get the expected outcome.
